# I want to return to the previous page after saving - ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

On the first page, I move to the next page, and I carry the ID number with me. For the employee on the first page.

On the second page, after completing the saving process, I want to return to the first page with me.

```
id number
```

For the employee on the first page

Page 1 "Employee"

[image]

Page 2 "Save new PC" - I get Employee id when come from page 1:

```
https://localhost:7119/Admin/Pc/Edit?empId=1
```

[image]

I can move Employee id from page 1 to page 2, but after saving new PC on page 2, I can't return to page 1.

I am using this code to return IF I come with Employee id

[image]

but I got this error:

[image]

Comment: don't recompute the url and pass that to the view. `View(...)` takes the action name

Comment: but i want after saveing back with employee id

Comment: Right but use the action name, not url

Answer (score 0):

When you use `return View();` in that case view discovery searches for a matching view file in Views or Views/Shared. so view name should start with "Views". you could try using this `return View("Views/Home/Edit.cshtml", user);` to resolve the issue or using the view directly with the url parameter you could try using the `RedirectToAction`.it provide you the way to accept additional parameters to pass data between actions.

Here is the sample code:

```
if (empld != null) 
{
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Edit), new { empId = empld });
}
```

Make sure in the Edit controller you have code to accept `empId` parameter.

```
public IActionResult Edit(int? empId)
```

if you also want to carry some additional data back to the edit page you could use the `TempData` or the session to persist that data across redirects.

Comment: Not Working ........

Comment: @ATA could you please share what is the result you are getting after applying the suggested changes?